# Does somebody know, why this even compile?

Tags: swift

There is a lot of different Double initializers, but any should except String as a parameter.

Why this compile (and returns a value!) ???

```
if let d = Double("0xabcdef10.abcdef10") {
    print(d)
}
```

it prints

```
2882400016.671111
```

no import required, please guys, check it with Your environment ...

**UPDATE**
Thank You guys, My trouble is not to uderstand how to represent Double value as a hexadecimal string.

I am confused with inconsistent implemetation of

```
protocol LosslessStringCovertible

 init?(_:) REQUIRED
 Instantiates an instance of the conforming type from a string representation.

 Declaration
 init?(_ description: String)
```

Both of Double and Int conforms to LosslessStringCovertible (Int indirectly, via conformance to FixedWidthInteger)

At the begining I started with

```
public func getValue<T: LosslessStringConvertible>(_ value: String)->T {
    guard let ret = T.init(value) else {
        // should never happen
        fatalError("failed to assign to \(T.self)")
    }
    return ret
}
// standart notation
let id: Int = getValue("15")
// hexadecimal notation
let ix: Int = getValue("0Xf") // Fatal error: failed to assign to Int
```

OK, that is implementation detail, so I decided to implemet it by my own, which accept string with binary, oktal, hexadecimal notation

next I did the same for Double and by testing it I found that when I forgot to import my LosslessStringConvertibleExt, my tests passed for expected Double where the string was in hexadecimal notation and in decimal notation.

Thank You **LeoDabus** for Your comment with the link to docs, which I didn't find before (yes, most likely I am blinded, it saves me few hours :-)

I appologize the rest of You for the "stupid" question.

Comment: I'm not certain I understand the question. Why *wouldn't* that work? Hexadecimal is just a different base for writing down digits. Why couldn't you have a decimal point?

Comment: from the docs **A hexadecimal value contains the significand, either 0X or 0x, followed by a sequence of hexadecimal digits. The significand may include a decimal point.
let f = Double("0x1c.6")
// f == 28.375
A hexadecimal value may also include an exponent following the significand, indicating the power of 2 by which the significand should be multiplied. If included, the exponent is separated by a single character, p or P, and consists of an optional plus or minus sign character and a sequence of decimal digits.
let g = Double("0x1.c6p4")
// g == 28.375**

Comment: Just option click Double init `Double.init("0xabcdef10")` and read it https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/double/2926277-init

Comment: @LeoDabus  that is my trouble, because I believed no init accepts String value. Will check it again ... I made my own extensions for Int and Double which excepts strings in form “0x...”, “0o...”, “0b...” and finally I found some collision, while testing.

Answer (score 3):

From the documentation of `Double`'s failable `init`:

> A hexadecimal value contains the significand, either `0X` or `0x`, followed by a sequence of hexadecimal digits. The significand may include a decimal point.
>
> `let f = Double("0x1c.6") // f == 28.375`

So `0xabcdef10.abcdef10` is interpreted as an hexadecimal number, given the `0x` prefix.

Answer (score 0):

The string was interpreted as fractional hex. Here's how the decimal value is calculated:

```
| Hex Digit | Decimal Value | Base Multipler | Decimal Result            |
|-----------|---------------|----------------|---------------------------|
| a         | 10            | x 16 ^ 7       |  2,684,354,560.0000000000 |
| b         | 11            | x 16 ^ 6       |    184,549,376.0000000000 |
| c         | 12            | x 16 ^ 5       |     12,582,912.0000000000 |
| d         | 13            | x 16 ^ 4       |        851,968.0000000000 |
| e         | 14            | x 16 ^ 3       |         57,344.0000000000 |
| f         | 15            | x 16 ^ 2       |          3,840.0000000000 |
| 1         | 1             | x 16 ^ 1       |             16.0000000000 |
| 0         | 0             | x 16 ^ 0       |              0.0000000000 |
| .         |               |                |                           |
| a         | 10            | x 16 ^ -1      |              0.6250000000 |
| b         | 11            | x 16 ^ -2      |              0.0429687500 |
| c         | 12            | x 16 ^ -3      |              0.0029296875 |
| d         | 13            | x 16 ^ -4      |              0.0001983643 |
| e         | 14            | x 16 ^ -5      |              0.0000133514 |
| f         | 15            | x 16 ^ -6      |              0.0000008941 |
| 1         | 1             | x 16 ^ -7      |              0.0000000037 |
| 0         | 0             | x 16 ^ -8      |              0.0000000000 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Total     |               |                |  2,882,400,016.6711100000 |
```